# Only ITEM QUANTITY is render to the cart

Tags: php

I'm trying to render the data for a specific item. At first I used a code which render its quantity and its ID. Well its work.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
//render the cart for the user to view
$cartOutput = "";
if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
    }else{
        $i = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
            $i++;
            $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                $price = $row["price"];

            }
            $cartOutput .= "<h2>Cart Item $i</h2>";


            while(list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                $cartOutput .= "$key: $value<br>";
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

But when I try to make more specific like only rendering its Id, name, price and quantity. It can only render its quantity.

Here it is:

```
<?php
//render the cart for the user to view
$cartOutput = "";
if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
    }else{
        $i = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
            $i++;
            $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                $price = $row["price"];

            }
            $cartOutput .= "<h2>Cart Item $i</h2>";
            $cartOutput .= "Item ID : " .$each_item['item_id'] . "<br>";
            $cartOutput .= "Item Quantity : " .$each_item['quantity'] . "<br>";
            $cartOutput .= "Item Name : " .$product_name . "<br>";
            $cartOutput .= "Item Price : Php. " .$price . "<br>";


            }
        }
?>
```

Can someone guide me here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be the problem is with the scope of variables. You are getting value of product name and price inside while  loop and referring it out side while loop. Define variable above while loop just below foreach statement like $product_name=''. Hope this will help you.

Comment: it doesn't work it gives me Notice saying its Undefined variable row in /home/a9562316/public_html/cart.php on line 53

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that either the query failed or the field names you have used are wrong. Try adding this piece of code to check both possibilities.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");

if ( $sql === false ) {
    echo 'Query Failed: ' . mysql_error();
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    print_r($row);   // check the field names in this array

    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $price = $row["price"];

}
```

**ADDITIONAL SUGGESTION**

Try this instead, I just saw that the output code was not inside the while loop. Not that you actually need a while loop as you have limited the query to return only one result `LIMIT 1`.

```
<?php
//render the cart for the user to view
$cartOutput = "";
if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
}else{
    $i = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
        $i++;
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            // no real point in moving these values to another variable
            // just to print them
            //$product_name = $row["product_name"];
            //$price = $row["price"];

            $cartOutput .= "<h2>Cart Item $i</h2>";
            $cartOutput .= "Item ID : " . $each_item['item_id'] . "<br>";
            $cartOutput .= "Item Quantity : " .$each_item['quantity'] . "<br>";
            $cartOutput .= "Item Name : " . $row["product_name"] . "<br>";
            $cartOutput .= "Item Price : Php. " . $row["price"] . "<br>";
        }    
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: where should I add this? Or should I change my codes using this?

Comment: This is your code with a couple of lines added. It should be fairly obvious.

Comment: Oh thanks. I've tried and still it only gives me the quantity. And my page showing Notice saying its Undefined variable at product_name and price in ....blah..blah..blah in line 68 and 69.

Comment: Does the `print_r($row)` show the array with a value for `$row['product_name']` and `$row['price']`

Comment: See additional suggestion

Comment: Still doesn't work nothings render. See my site speedsign.site88.net try to add product to cart to see the result. And thank you for your suggestions. I appreciate.